# How to resume the mediaplayer?

Tags: android, media-player

I am using a media player.

I have the option for starting ,stopping and pausing the player. The problem I have is that I cannot find the option to resume the song from the point that it previously was paused..

Any help provide would be really helpful.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Thank you for your attention but I've got it myself

for pausing the Mediaplayer I used:

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

and for resuming the player from the position where it stopped lately is done by:

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

Comment: It worked for me on Galaxy tab 2 but didn't work on Acer Iconia or Nexus 7. I don't know what is wrong with starting player from not 0 position but obviously something is.

Comment: this doesn't work for me! no errors but the sound doesn't resume! what's my error?

Comment: I didn't have to use `MediaPlayer.seekTo(length)`; I simply called MediaPlayer.start() and it resumed, as the documentation states (see answer below).

Answer (score 28):

I think you should go through the documentation found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Some quotes from the docs:

> Playback can be paused and stopped,
> and the current playback position can
> be adjusted. Playback can be paused
> via pause(). When the call to pause()
> returns, the MediaPlayer object enters
> the Paused state. Note that the
> transition from the Started state to
> the Paused state and vice versa
> happens asynchronously in the player
> engine. It may take some time before
> the state is updated in calls to
> isPlaying(), and it can be a number of
> seconds in the case of streamed
> content.
>
> - Calling start() to resume
>   playback for a paused MediaPlayer
>   object, and the resumed playback
>   position is the same as where it was
>   paused. When the call to start()
>   returns, the paused MediaPlayer object
>   goes back to the Started state.
> - Calling pause() has no effect on a
>   MediaPlayer object that is already in
>   the Paused state.

States explained:

[image: States of MediaPlayer]

And quote from the start() method of the MediaPlayer

> public void start ()
>
> Starts or resumes
> playback. If playback had previously
> been paused, playback will continue
> from where it was paused. If playback
> had been stopped, or never started
> before, playback will start at the
> beginning.

So to answer your question directly, to resume the paused MediaPlayer instance from the point where it was paused use start() again on that instance.

Answer (score 18):

In the accepted answer, the correct order is:

```
Mediaplayer.start();
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
```

---

Answer (score 2):

in case you use two Buttons one for play and one for pause then the below code is working and tried:

```
                playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,         
                    R.raw.adhan);

                    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {


                    } else {
                        mPlayer.seekTo(length);
                        mPlayer.start();
                      }

                }
                });

               pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mPlayer.pause();
                    length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   public void play(View view) {
           mediaPlayer.start();
   }
   public void pause(View view){
           mediaPlayer.pause();
   }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.someaudio);
    }
}
```

Make two buttons for play and pause. And use this code. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

what about this way?

```
     package com.mycompany.audiodemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=null;
    int playPosition=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sampleaudio);
    }

    public void playAudio(View view){

        //mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void pauseAudio(View view){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        //playPosition =  mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```