# Android media player : How can I listen for media player events?

Tags: android, android-activity, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am following the [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) explanation of the `MediaPlayer` and I am wondering how can I listen to the events from the player such as playing, paused, stopped etc...

The page shows how to listen only for the `onPreparedListener` and so I was wondering if there are events for the the other states of the player, or how would I handle the different states of the player?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not detect if the `mediaplayer` is paused or stopped, The `MediaPlayer` class has one function `isPlaying()` which will detect if it's in playing mode or not. You can do some effort for detecting pause condition as below :

```
mediaplayer.pause();
//get the length of the mediaplayer here
length=mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
//and for resume you can do the following
mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
mediaplayer.start();
```

For checking stopping state of mediaplayer, you can check as above , the only change will be the time which will reach to maximum. That's all. Or, You can use `setOnCompletionListener()`

Also check this answer , how mediaplayer reaches different states. [**Click here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855151/how-to-resume-the-mediaplayer/3855609#3855609)

The mediaplayer contains following listener :

```
 1. setOnBufferingUpdateListener
 2. setOnErrorListener
 3. setOnInfoListener
 4. setOnCompletionListener
 5. setOnSeekCompleteListener
 6. setOnTimedTextListener
 7. setOnVideoSizeChangedListener
 8. setOnPreparedListener
```

Hope this will help you . :)

Comment: @Caius Sure thing! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [`VideoView`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) that implements some of the listeners like `onCompletion`, `onError` etc. The initialization of various listeners can be found at this [location](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java#324).

You can also refer to the `MediaPlayerTest` in `CTS` for additional examples as can be found [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/cts/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaPlayerTest.java#992).