# Android Audio Player Start playing another song with already playing song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I m Making an audio player (android).The question is when i  start my app > play Song >press the back key or home the song Still play's in background But when i open the app again it start new song playing where the old song is also playing. How to get Rid of this?

Comment: You can release the media player on destroy of activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem Was i was not aware of Service which run in background. Now i am using a service for plating song and updating activity UI from service and when my app is in background the song plays and as i reopen the app and select another song the previous stop playing and new song start playing 
Thanks every body for help

Answer (score 2):

Stop and release the `media player` in the `onDestroy`, example :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mp!=null){
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i Don't want to destroy. I want that when i resume the app the player also resumes from there.

Comment: @XäiñUlAbideen Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855151/how-to-resume-the-mediaplayer Or do some googling, combine it with my answer :)

Comment: @XäiñUlAbideen Please accept my answer, since i answered your main question about stopping the media player :)

Comment: i appropriate your answer but i already know that . i want to make my app work in background also so will you please guide me brother ????

Answer (score 1):

Use `mediaplayer.reset();` after `stop()` method before playing new song.

Add these points in select & play new song method:

1. Check if the track is playing:

   ```
   if(mp.isPlaying())
   ```

   ... where `mp` is `MediaPlayer` object.
2. If **yes** then stop play and then reset media player:

   ```
   mp.stop();  
   mp.reset();
   ```

   The `mp.reset()` will reset all initialization of MediaPlayer ex: song URI etc.

   If **not** then only reset media player:

   ```
   mp.reset();
   ```
3. Now get the position and the ID of newly selected track from the list and set it as new URI.
4. Play track based on new URI:

   ```
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, NewTrackUri);  
   mp.start();
   ```

   This should only play the newly selected track.