# play music again with key_down more than one time

Tags: android, eclipse

hi i have a short song  and a button . i want play the song repeatedly until user clicking the button and when user release it the song get stop. the problem is = it will play again but start from where that it paused i want start from began . how can i do something to make it work every time that user click = play from began

sorry for bad language

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button s1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    s1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        MediaPlayer sb1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ava);
        @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) 
        { 
            int action = motionevent.getAction(); 
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            { 

               sb1.setLooping(true);
               sb1.start();
            } 
            else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            { 
               sb1.pause();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Try with `sb1.pause()` instead of `sb1.stop()`. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855151/how-to-resume-the-mediaplayer.

Comment: sorry but its not what i want i want play song again from began can u help me in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use song.seekTo(0) ; after your song.pause ();