# MediaPlayer mp3 won't resume after pause, known solutions not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

My activity is playing mp3 file while is active, and my intention is to pause it while app takes user to another activity and resume when this activity is again active. Solution that was here around seems to be the right one but unfortunately id doesn't work, the audio file every time starts from beginning. My code is obvious:

```
private int length;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,  R.raw.bensound_thejazzpiano);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.4f,0.4f);
        mediaPlayer.start();
}

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
 mediaPlayer.start();

    }
```

I would also be satisfied with methods that mutes sound and restores the volume after goin back to activity (and muted tune can go on in background), but replacing start/stop methods with setVolume also doesn't provide to any results...

Maybe there are wrong methods I've overridden?

Comment: Try to switch the order of calling in `onResume()`. Call `mediaPlayer.start()` first .

Comment: nope, that doesn't make a change, I thing the problem might be that activity every time creates new media player and starts song from beginning, but how to solve that?

Comment: Activity will not create new instance unless its recreted . You have initialize `MediaPlayer` in `onCreate()`. Log the `Activity`s` state .

Comment: Activity states seems to work right because tune behaves as expected when I push home button on my app and then go back, it suspends and resumes. but doesn't do that when I go to another activity (which is done  by onClick and I have onPause method in that

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855151/how-to-resume-the-mediaplayer) if you already haven't.

Comment: yes, this is from I have my code above

Comment: it looks like getcurrentposition always returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "pause"(not stop) the mediaplayer in onPause, then start in onResume. That worked for me.