# Why MediaPlayer reset position after start again?

Tags: android

I create a activity play a video:

Init MediaPlayer and auto start play video

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
        // AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        // mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(FILE_NAME);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

                initializeSeekBar();
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

code of oncreate:

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress );
                }
            }   

        });
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                }
                else
                { 

Log.d("daitran",String.valueOf(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                        int currentpos=mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();        
 Log.d("daitran",String.valueOf(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));          
               btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Update value of seekbar:

```
protected void initializeSeekBar(){
        seekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
        //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
        E045.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){ 
                    Log.d("daitran",String.valueOf(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                    int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() ;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    if(mCurrentPosition==100)
                    {
                        btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    }
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

If i click button Pause/Start, it return correct Position,
But if Click Pause -> click to seekbar to change postion -> Click start, it can't start from new position.

Why MediaPlayer reset position after start again?
[image]

Log after play again:

```
09-05 17:27:03.936 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 12000
09-05 17:27:03.949 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 128
09-05 17:27:04.231 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 150
09-05 17:27:05.312 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 1232
09-05 17:27:06.318 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 2239
09-05 17:27:07.362 27287-27287/com.example.android.camera2video D/daitran: 3282
```

Comment: In your image, I saw that your highlighted 3 boxes and 2 of them are numbers, how do you get those numbers?

Comment: in my case its working fine

Comment: @Tay: debug of android studio, them will display.

Comment: @solanki: i updated Init MediaPlayer, Is it the same with your code?

Comment: Where is the code of your debug (usually using Log), I did not see any except in the exception handler

Comment: @Tay: i update log after play again.

Comment: @DT not sure but i post my answer with my code wich is working fine in all devices]

Comment: my answer may helps you @DT

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resume from a particular position you should do like this:

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(targetPosition);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

so `targetPosition` is the position you want to resume from there

Comment: so just seek to that pos, and then start mediaPlayer

Comment: i had try, but it still reset after start

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [How to resume the mediaplayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855151/how-to-resume-the-mediaplayer)

for pausing the Mediaplayer I used:

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

and for resuming the player from the position where it stopped lately is done by:

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```